# How to open a specific PayPal link in the PayPal iOS app from my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I have an http PayPal URL with some parameters that leads to a payment page for some item.
E.g. https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=foobar@fakeserver.com&item_name=Some+item&amount=2.50 leads to the page for this dummy item with parameters item_name="Some item" and amount="2.50".

All I need to do is open that page in the iOS PayPal app - from my iOS app. Just like you would open a Facebook page in the Facebook app with `"fb://page?id=%@"`. I don't need to implement any PayPal functions in my app or get any data back from it, so I don't think I need the PayPal iOS SDK or any other API.

The PayPal app URL scheme is **paypal://xxx**, but I don't know what goes after it. I've been searching for a whole day now with no results whatsoever. All I know is that
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"paypal://anything"]]`
opens the PayPal app, but it just shows the home/previous view. I have no idea how to open any specific page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

@user282378 you should open that URL just as it is, with its `https://` URL scheme. I.e., the URL will open in Safari.

The PayPal app does indeed support a `paypal://` URL scheme. However this URL scheme is intended only for certain limited PayPal usage. It is not a general-purpose scheme for use by non-PayPal apps.

Comment: Dave, is it possible to open the PayPal app from another app and start a payment transaction? What's the limited PayPal usage you're talking about?

Comment: @3000 By "limited PayPal usage" I meant "certain limited usage **by PayPal**". In other words, `paypal://` is a url-scheme intended for use only by certain apps created by PayPal. Your app should never use this url-scheme.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks Dave. Problem is they told me about an app (its name is YPlan or something similar) that launches the PayPal native iOS app and lets you pay throught that. I was investigating about this thing when I found your comment

Comment: can you give me full URL?