# How to check if PayPal app is installed on iPhone from code?

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

This is how I check if WeChat app is installed:

```
static func isWechatAvailable() -> Bool {
    if let url = NSURL(string:"weixin://scanqrcode")?.absoluteURL, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

How do I do it for PayPal? PayPal doesn't seem to have the scheme url. And installing and using PayPal SDK is a huge amount of work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: that may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30310162/1214122

Answer (score 2):

First you need to provide a LSApplicationQueriesSchemes entry in plist file, declaring which schemes it attempts to query. In your case its PayPal app.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>paypal</string>
</array>
```

Then modify your function like this.

```
static func isPayPalAvailable() -> Bool {
    if let url = NSURL(string:"paypal:")?.absoluteURL, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

You will get true if device has PayPal app installed. In case if you want to check it for other apps, replace paypal with other app name.

Answer (score 0):

you should open that URL just as it is, with its https:// URL scheme. So that the URL will open in Safari.

`paypal://` URL scheme is intended only for certain limited PayPal usage